# How to input a lot of data until you type in an invalid number in java

Tags: java, loops

User inputs numbers one by one and then once they type in an invalid number (has to be from 1-200) the program calculates the average of the numbers that were inputted.

I'm just wondering what would the code be for this. I know the one for inputting one piece of data. Example would be:

```
 `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 String numberOfShoes = "";

 System.out.println("Enter the number of shoes you want: (0-200) ");
 numberOfShoes = in.nextLine();`
```

this is just an example, but this time I want the user to input a lot of numbers. I know I'm going to include a loop somewhere in this and I have to stop it once it contains an invalid number (using a try catch block).

*** I would also like to add that once the user inputs another number it always goes to the next line.

Comment: Use a `do{} while()` loop. `Do` - ask user for a number `While` - number is in the correct range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a while loop to continue taking input until a condition is met. Also keep variables to track the sum, and the total number of inputs.

I would also suggest having `numberOfShoes` be an `int` and use the `nextInt()` method on your `Scanner`  (so you don't have to convert from `String` to `int`).

```
System.out.println("Enter your number of shoes: ");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int numberOfShoes = 0;
int sum = 0;
int numberOfInputs = 0;

do {
    numberOfShoes = in.nextInt();

    if (numberOfShoes >= 1 && numberOfShoes <= 200) { // if valid input
        sum += numberOfShoes;
        numberOfInputs++;
    }

} while (numberOfShoes >= 1 && numberOfShoes <= 200); // continue while valid

double average = (double)sum / numberOfInputs;

System.out.println("Average: " + average);
```

---

#### Sample:

```
Enter your number of shoes: 
5
3
7
2
0
Average: 4.25
```

It added `5 + 3 + 7 + 2` to get the `sum` of `17`. Then it divided `17` by the `numberOfInputs`, which is `4` to get `4.25`

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense! Now I just have to add a try catch block for the illegalargumentexception if it is an invalid number. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

you are almost there.

Logic is like this,

```
   Define array

    Begin Loop
     Accept the number
     check if its invalid number [it is how u define a invalid number]
       if invalid, Exit Loop
       else  put it in the array

    End Loop

    Add all numbers in your array
```

Comment: Loop - you can use do{...}while(); To Exit loop, you can use break

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do something like this (which @Takendarkk suggested):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class shoes {

    public void main(String[] args){
        int input = 0;
        do{
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            String numberOfShoes = "";

            System.out.println("Enter the number of shoes you want: (0-200) ");
            numberOfShoes = in.nextLine();
            input = Integer.parseInt(numberOfShoes);
        }while((input>=0) && (input<=200));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for loop like this

```
for(::)
{
    //do your input and processing here

    if(terminating condition satisified)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```